# Can I delete the $WinREAgent folder?

Tags: windows

Can I delete the $WinREAgent folder?

Or the "scratch" folder under it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you  can delete it. No harm done. I just deleted the one on my machine. No issue.

Windows will recreate it when it needs it (updates).

Now, while you can delete it, there is not much gained by doing so. I leave mine in place.

Purely personal preference.

Here is a resource to help you.

[Delete $WinREagent[1](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/what_is_the_winreagent_folder_and_can_i_delete_it.html#:%7E:text=Can%20I%20Delete%20the%20%24WinREAgent,can%20delete%20the%20%24WinREAgent%20Folder.)

> Can I Delete the $WinREAgent Folder?
>
> The short answer is yes; you can delete the $WinREAgent Folder.
>
> Before deleting the $WinREAgent folder, we would check for, and
> install any pending Windows Updates - if you don't have any updates
> available, reboot and remove the $WinREAgent folder if it remains.
>
> Conversely, deleting the $WinREAgent folder might solve problems if
> Windows Update is not working.

Comment: What you wish to do works.  Is there anything else you need  @Jonesome Reinstate Monica    ?

Comment: John, we always appreciate the contributions based upon your expertise, but do you have any official references regarding the $WinREAgent folder to support that assessment?

Comment: It is simply a temp folder that Microsoft creates.   It is not secured against deletion.I have checked several systems and one can delete this folder. There is no reference I have see on temporary Microsoft folders.

Comment: I did (to assist everyone) add an explanatory resource to my answer.   @Run5k